# DNS - Pointing A Record to new IP for SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, networking, dns, propagation

I have a subdomain sub.domain.co.uk that points to my server ip address lets say 192.0.2.1 currently this just uses http.

I have a need to make this use https/ssl so I have purchased my SSL but my server host have advised I need to point my url sub.domain.co.uk to a different IP in order for the SSL to work so I can hook it up in IIS.

So now I need to point sub.domain.co.uk to 192.0.2.**2**

So the only way forward I can see is that I go into my DNS settings in 123 reg and change my sub.domain.co.uk A record from 192.0.2.1 to 192.0.2.**2**

And incurr the downtime/propagation that comes with that.

Am I missing something, is there a better way to do this without incurring downtime?

For example, could I just add a second A NAME, for the same sub domain, e.g...

sub 192.0.2.1
sub 192.0.2.2

and in IIS just point my SSL to the second one, or would that confuse browsers?

Any help appreciated in advance

Comment: Are you configuring IIS by yourself or your server hosters will be doing that?

Comment: I have full control over IIS and the server

Comment: Well, I don't know what could be the reasoning behind their advice, but I suggest you just configure new https website in IIS, on the same (existing) ip address, it should just work without any other changes.

Comment: I cant do that I am afriad, after looking into it. My IIS setup for this site is currently set to * which I think just means all unassigned. And I have already setup 1 SSL certificate for another site under * (which feels like a mistake now) so i do need to use a fixed ip

Comment: That shouldn't matter, new virtualhost/website needs to have at least one of these 3 things unique/notequal: ipaddress, port, hostname. So, if your new hostname is different/unique, that is enough that it can also run on the same ipaddress(es) and port

Comment: Hello, Thank you, if I attempt to do that I get the following...

At least one other site is using the same HTTPS binding and the binding is configured with a different certificate. are you sure that you want to reuse this HTTPS binding and reassign the other site or sites to use the new certificate?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have solved this myself after a little research.

So I have two websites in IIS with an SSL that are using * as the ip address, meaning use any unassigned ip's.

So when I tried to add the SSL to the second website it complains saying that cause issues with the bindings on the first.

So if I just tick the little box that says 'Require Server Name Indication' on my second IIS bindings (when applying the SSL) it works perfectly.

Great article on Server Name Indication below (SNI)

https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-is-sni/

Comment: Yep, SNI is mandatory these days (it is strange that it is not activated by default)